# How does Marshal.ReadInt32 etc. differ from unsafe context and pointers?

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged

Particularly: Is Marshal safer? Are pointers faster?

```
int pixel = Marshal.ReadInt32(bitmapData.Scan0, x * 4 + y * bitmapData.Stride);
int pixel = ((int*)bitmapData.Scan0)[x + y * bitmapData.Stride / 4];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. If you look at the code from `Marshal.ReadInt32` you will see it uses pointers to perform the same thing.

The only 'benefit' with `Marshal` is that you not have to explicitly allow unsafe code. IIRC, you also require FullTrust to run unsafe code, so that may be a consideration.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say that there is a performance difference, I believe it's due to function invocation. It's minuscule if you're not doing many marshalling calls, but for iterating over bitmaps it can be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using `Marshal` mostly because I shun unsafe code. As to which is faster, I'm not sure but I am certain that operating pixel by pixel is liable to be slow however you do it.  Much better is to read an entire scanline into a C# array and work on that.

Comment: Reading the scanline into an array would require a copy which could take much more space/memory/time.

Comment: @leppie Actually, reading a scanline into an array would result in a copy which would likely take less time than pixel by pixel copying.

Comment: Who is copying pixels? Normally one would just operate on the value and discard it (or move to the next value).

Comment: @leppie It's being copied into `pixel`

Comment: What's wrong with operating on the native array directly? Or: who says managed arrays are faster than native ones?

Comment: No, that is simply a local/stack variable. What happens with it cant be assumed. I agree if you want to do the whole image at once, then the array approach might be better. But again, it is anyone's guess what happens after the assignment.